# How to mud over areas where old trim was?

Tags: drywall-mud

I have a small alcove in an old house. It had wood trim that been painted over like 10 times, as well as the walls. I removed the wood trim and am considering the next step.

Would it be feasible to cover the wood with drywall, put corner beads around all corners, and mud the areas where the old wood trim was?

More specifically, the gap from the drywall to the area where the old trim was is about 1/4 inch, and I'm worried its to big of a gap to fill up.

Regardless, should it be done using hot mud or all purpose mud? Or both? Do I need to put tape anywhere or is corner beads enough?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Would it be feasible to cover the wood with drywall, and put corner beads around all corners, and hotmud the areas where the old wood trim was?", it's feasible, but what's your intended outcome?  If you don't like having trim there and you want a smooth finish, then that to me sounds like your only option.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking about overall strategy, or whether you can use setting-type joint compound, or whether you can avoid taping? Please revise to be more specific. Maybe make your title a bit less vague. See [ask].

Comment: That edge around that missing surface at the upper left corner seems to indicate a plaster veneer. Is there a layer of plaster on top?

Comment: Yeah, it was coated over with mud I believe. The mud didn't stick to some areas and comes off in small sheets. However, the mud was never primed and painted...!